# Sims 2 Ultimate Collection on Origin locked at 800x600

Tags: technical-issues, windows-10, origin, the-sims-2

I have tried using the Sims 2/SC4 graphics rules maker tool as well as manual editing to fix this, but neither method worked. Is `The Sims 2 Ultimate Collection\Fun with Pets\SP9` not the correct version of the Sims 2 to edit? How do I make the Sims 2 run at 1080p?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the mystery! Graphics rules maker was editing the high preset, and so was I. However, the game was looking at the low preset, so I changed the low preset. Problem solved.